# How to find the Postion of all matching substrings in a QStringList

Tags: c++, qt

i am looking for a way to find the cell position of all matching substrings in a `QStringList`.

The List is filled form a txt file looking like that:

```
10:36:50,590/2002/1800

10:36:50,621/2002/1801

10:36:50,652/2002/1802

10:36:50,684/2002/1803

10:36:50,715/2002/1803

10:36:50,746/2002/1803

10:36:50,777/2002/1803/0/0/Target_Hit
 
10:36:50,809/2002/1802

10:36:50,840/2002/1802

10:36:50,871/2002/1802

10:36:50,965/2000/1831/0/0/Target_Hit
```

Each cell of the `QStringList` contain one line of the txt file.
Now i want to find the absolut number of hits and postion of the cells conatining the substring `"Target_Hit"`.

I tried to find the number of it like that:
`int number_of_hits = List.indexOf(QRegExp(".*\Target_Hit$));` but that returns a `-1`
so i guess the `QRegExp` is incorrect.

Comment: I would recommend you change your reading of the file to actually parse the input, and put it into structure objects. Then you can have a container of those objects, and can easily find all elements that matches your criteria, without needing to resort to regular expressions.

Comment: However, with your current string list, you don't need regular expressions either. Just iterate over the list, and find strings that contains the sub-string `"Target_Hit"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use indexOf for this because it would only return you one index, and it seems that you are looking for multiple.

I would read the file line by line, check each line if it contains what you are looking for, and take note of that, effectively this pseudo code:

```
initialise a counter to zero.
initialise a position list to an empty list.
read each line
    check if the line contains the search string.
    if it does: append the position into a list and increment the counter.
    continue the next line.
```

Then, at the end, you could have all that you desired to have.